# Allow only one checked checkbox, Angular best practice.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using angular. 
I have Three checkboxes in a Group and i want to make sure only one of them can be checked. So if one is checked the other two has to bee unchacked. I can Think of doing this several ways with native JS or jQuery but i want to know if there is a typical Angular way of doing it.

Here is Plunker with a set up of the checkboxes and angular controll. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/IZmGwktrCaYNyrWjfSqf?p=preview

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div>
    {{vm.Output}}

    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a1" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A1 </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a2" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A2 </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a3" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A3 </label>

    <br>
    <br>
    <br> {{vm.Output}}
</body>
```

Comment: Shouldnt you be using radio buttons then? If only one of them can be checked? http://plnkr.co/edit/uXoLoqO4gap0Xg9SpTle?p=preview

Comment: I tried that but no. Because of specifics of the task. Radio buttons cant be unchecked and the model has no room for an extra 'none selected' radio button.

Comment: Honestly, changing the design to make room for a 4th radio button makes a lot more sense then using checkboxes for this.

Comment: Using built-in, native radio is definitely best practice. Just uncheck everything when a checked radio is clicked.

Comment: Ok, but im not allowed to do that. If i would be i know how to do it. Its not what i need help with.

Comment: if you dont want to use the radio buttons, use the function to change other model values to false?

Comment: Maanus so how would that best be done with Angular.... is kind of my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't use radio buttons, I've made this plnkr when you check one the others are deselected:

http://plnkr.co/edit/apSE3cIXA7DIvulBfNGX?p=preview

```
 <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a1" ng-change="vm.a2 = false; vm.a3 = false; vm.changeGroupA()" >  A1  </label> 
 <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a2" ng-change="vm.a1 = false; vm.a3 = false; vm.changeGroupA()" >  A2  </label>
 <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a3" ng-change="vm.a2 = false; vm.a1 = false; vm.changeGroupA()" >  A3  </label>
```

Hope it helps =)

Edit: You can probably change the state of the other checkboxes in the controller for best practice, made in the html just to demonstrate more quickly..

Comment: BRILLIANT! I knew there was a good angular way of doing it. I love you.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be: http://plnkr.co/edit/kH12pYkXfY6t6enrlSns

```
  <br><br><br>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.groupA[0]" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA(0)" >  A1  </label> 
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.groupA[1]" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA(1)" >  A2  </label>
  <label> <input type="checkbox" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.groupA[2]" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA(2)" >  A3  </label>

  <br><br><br>
```

The controller would look like this:

```
$scope.vm = {

  groupA: [false, true, false],
  count : 0,

  changeGroupA : function (index)
  {


    for (i = 0, len = this.groupA.length; i < len; ++i) {
      this.groupA[i] = ((1 << index) & (1 << i)) > 0;
    }


    this.Output = '(' + this.count + ')' + this.Output;
    this.count ++;

  },

  Output : 'Here we go'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do it the hard way out. http://plnkr.co/edit/A53w4IJMRXQmvRsxa8JA and it should work

`changeGroupA : function (x)
  {
    if (x === 'A1'){
      $scope.vm.a1 = true;
      $scope.vm.a2 = false;
      $scope.vm.a3 = false;
    }
    else if (x === 'A2') {
      $scope.vm.a2 = true;
      $scope.vm.a1 = false;
      $scope.vm.a3 = false;
    }
    else if (x === 'A3') {
      $scope.vm.a3 = true;
      $scope.vm.a1 = false;
      $scope.vm.a2 = false;
    }
    this.Output = '(' + this.count + ')' + this.Output;
    this.count ++;
  },`

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly fine for angular 6 or 8

HTML:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check1id" 
                [(ngModel)]="check1" (change)="onlyOneValue($event)"/>
                <label for="check1id" class="custom-control-label">Checkbox 1</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="check2id"
                [(ngModel)]="check2" (change)="onlyOneValue($event)" />
                <label for="check2id" class="custom-control-label"> Checkbox 2 </label>
</div>
```

.ts code:

```
check1=false;
check2=false;
onlyOneValue(e)
{
  if (e.target.id == "Check1id") {
      this.Check1= true;
      this.Check2 = false;
    }
 else  if (e.target.id == "Check1id") {
      this.Check1= true;
      this.Check2 = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just use a radio button?

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a1" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A1 </label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a2" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A2 </label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="groupA" ng-model="vm.a3" ng-change="vm.changeGroupA()"> A3 </label>
```

Comment: I tried that but no. Because of specifics of the task. Radio buttons cant be unchecked and the model has no room for an extra 'none selected' radio button

Comment: Sorry, you probably should have put that in your original question.