# How do you use radio button to toggle between true and false values? Using Angular and Reactive Forms (FormArray)

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Here is the radio button that I have in a FormArray.

```
   <input
               
                type="radio"
                formControlName="correctAnswer"
                value=""
                name="correctAnswer"
                
              />
```

When the radio is selected, I want the value I get returned to be 'true'.  When it's unselected, I want the value returned to be 'false'.  This value is to be kept within the radio input itself, so that it displays in the value of my FormArray.

Any thoughts?  I considered doing checkboxes, but I can only have one selected at a time.  I basically need a checkbox that acts like a radio in the sense that it only one FormArray can be true.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it´s better use a checkbox:

```js
<mat-checkbox formControlName="active" id="activeFilter">Active</mat-checkbox>
```

but if you want use a radiobutton maybe it will work if you initialize this value in your formGroup.

```js
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  active: new FormControl(false),
});
```

And specify the values ​​in html:

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="active">
  <mat-radio-button value="true">True</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="false">False</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: How would you propose doing it as checkbox?  I will still need it to only select one.  I would rather go with checkbox as well, since it auto-populates my values into the array. I'm just stumped on being able to select only one.

Comment: I have modified my answer so that you can also see how it would be with a checkbox, it is easier because they work with boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons aren't meant to hold true/false values in a sense that the toggled state is true false. The value should be either present or not - toggled or not. I would also suggest checkbox for such operations (which could look like radio buttons if needs be). But... we could do something like this:

```js
/**
 * @title Radios with ngModel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'radio-ng-model-example',
  templateUrl: 'radio-ng-model-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['radio-ng-model-example.css'],
})
export class RadioNgModelExample {

  seasons: any[] = [
    { name: 'Winter', value: false },
    { name: 'Spring', value: false },
    { name: 'Summer', value: false },
    { name: 'Autumn', value: false },
  ];
  
}
```

```html
<label id="example-radio-group-label">Pick your favorite season</label>
<br />
<ng-container *ngFor="let season of seasons">
  <mat-radio-button
    name="{{season.name}}"
    class="example-radio-button"
    [checked]="season.value === true"
    [value]="season.value"
    (click)="season.value = !season.value">
    {{season.name}} current value is {{season.value}}
  </mat-radio-button>
  <br />
</ng-container>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcrva2-cxphui?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-ng-model-example.html

If you need formControls on the radio buttons, each radio button should be in within its own radio group for a template driven form control, or use reactive approach and read values from `seasons[]`.

Comment: Great example! If I were to go with checkboxes (which I would prefer), how would you recommend only being able to select one checkbox at a time?

Comment: To use method, that when checking one, un-checks any others. Here's a basic representation of the idea:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39919824/15439733